# Complexity of Sorting in Single Loop

Tags: arrays, loops, sorting, for-loop, time-complexity

```
function sortArrays(arr)
{
 // Sorting using a single loop
 for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {

 // Checking the condition for two
 // simultaneous elements of the array
 if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
   
 // Swapping the elements.
 let temp = arr[j];
 arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
 arr[j + 1] = temp;
   
 // updating the value of j = -1
 // so after getting updated for j++
 // in the loop it becomes 0 and
 // the loop begins from the start.
 j = -1;
 }
}
 
return arr;
}
```

I am confused on this part that what will be complexity of this loop.
The loop will only get reversed when the condition gets true. So I believe that the complexity lies in between O(n) and  O'Log(n).

Comment: That would be O(n^3), you might want to look at Bubble Sort and its time complexity as well.

Comment: How can this be of O(n^3). i didn't understood will you elaborate more?

Comment: Lets say that indexes `i` ,`j` are an inversion if `i < j` and `arr[i] > arr[j]`, those are a most swap in your algorithm in order to get the array sorted, if the array is sorted in reverse order there are O(n^2) inversions ( see Insertion Sort ), your algorithm re-starts the loop every time it finds one of these inversions, that means you could take at most O(n) time to find one inversion in the array, then by the principle of multiplication your algorithm is O(n^3).